# Why do I receive unhelpful results for subtractions?

Tags: java, double, calculator, precision

```
double foo = 3;
double bar = 2.1;

System.out.println(foo - bar + "");
```

Output:

```
0.8999999999999999
```

Why? Is this some Java joke, which is not understandable for mere mortals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't a joke.  [It is floating-point precision error problem.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)  The main gist of this problem is that floating points are represented in base 2 rather than 10, and that the precision of `doubles` is not arbitrary.

If you want precision, you can use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class:

Comment: Thank you, this pretty much sums up things.